# Echo colon array in table format

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I am not able to convert this array which is defined by colon to display in table (as mentioned below). Can anyone please guide me.

```
$info='Title:Beckham,Age:43,Address:UK';
```

Must look like this table format:

[image]

Comment: explode on comma, loop, explode on colon

Comment: I was confused on term to research on, Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: nice to hear u got help , u can tick mark my answer so others can get help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$info='Title:Beckham,Age:43,Address:UK'; 
$info_array = explode(",",$info); 
$table = "<table>";

foreach($info_array as $row){
    $row_obj_array = explode(":",$row);
    $table .= "<tr><td>$row_obj_array[0]</td><td>$row_obj_array[1]</td></tr>";
}

$table.="</table>";
echo $table;
?>
```

Comment: Nirpendra, it works. Thank you for helping me out.